# Login automation (Web crawling) issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler

so here is the story. There is a website for trading stocks and etc. which has a dashboard requires login with a username and password. In the dashboard you can watch the market, send orders and stuff like that. What I am trying to do is to create a bot that can make use of the api of related links to that site in order to login to send and receive data.I could find the links and related apis with help of inspect element tools in browsers. The POST login link is :

```
https://**stock.****.com/api/v2/mobile/login
```

I can send the username and password to this link as post request and successfully login into site and the following sessions are stored for later requests :

```
JWT-TOKEN=***; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

By using the store session I can do some get requests like from links like :

```
.../api/v2/user/buyingPower
```

But the problem is when I try sending requests to links like this one :

```
.../api/v1/adminMessages
```

Although the browser is sending request without problems but when I try it in java code or in postman, I get forbidden errors(not auth errors!).
I have done a huge search in all the js files of the site and found the function that sends ajax requests. It is like :

```
function ajax(n) {

    var t, i;

    if (!n.forceSend) {


        if (!window.getTimeIsDone) {
            !!waitForServerTime.find(function(t) {
                return t.url === n.url
            }) == !1 && waitForServerTime.push(n);
            return
        }


        if (!isRlcConnected() && n.url.includes(rlcWebUrl)) {
            showPopupNotification("There is no active connection to the market data server.", "error");
            return
        }

        if (!isExirConnected() && n.url.includes(exirWebBaseUrl)) {
            showPopupNotification("There is no active connection with the server.", "error");
            return
        }
        
    }


    if (n.dataType || (n.dataType = "json") , n.method || (n.method = "GET"), n.method && n.method != "OPTIONS" && n.method != "DELETE" && (n.contentType === !1 || n.contentType || (n.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8")), n.headers || (n.headers = {}), typeof user != "undefined") {
        
        var f = n.url.replace(exirWebBaseUrl, ""),//It gets the urls from some vars.

            r = globalActions.getUtcTime(-2e3),//gets global time

            e = user.nt.substr(2),//nt is a code received in first login response.

            u = 0;

        for (t = 0; t < f.length; t++) u += f.charCodeAt(t);

        


//here it generates a parameter called "X-App-N" to send it with the request.I could generate it my self.
        n.headers["X-App-N"] = (Number.parseInt(     e.substr(Math.abs(i % (e.length - 5) - Number.parseInt(user.nt.substr(0, 2))), 5)    ) * i * u).toString() + "." + i * u;

        window.appendXAppN = n.headers["X-App-N"];
        debugMode && !n.headers.authToken && user.authToken && (n.headers.authToken = user.authToken)

    }

//also the authToken is received in the login response in first place.

    n.cache = !0;
    $.ajax(n)

}
```

I have added some comments among the code above. I can not really figure out the problem. I have included all the headers needed but can not understand why it is ok in browser but not successful in postman or java code.
the headers I include :

```
//Cookie:cookiesession1=***; _ga=***; _gid=***; PLAY_SESSION=***-authToken=***
Host:***.***.com
Referer:https://***.***.com/api/v1/adminMessages
Sec-Fetch-Mode:cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:same-origin
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0
X-App-N:3563754737200.63534100
DNT:1
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection:keep-alive
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Sec-Fetch-Dest:empty
authToken:***
Cache-Control:no-cache
dataType:json
```

It can be really great if you can give me any hint or idea that I can work it out.

Comment: Have you tried copying the request from the browser devtools? Maybe you are missing some cookies, or a specific header? Or maybe you send too many headers. Other than that, I want to warn you that this type of API usage is disallowed by most trading sites. If they don't offer a public API, it is probably against their TOS and by breaking it you risk getting in trouble. I suspect you are using a real account with your credentials, address, and so on behind it, so be careful!

Comment: MauriceNino, Thanks for the response. I actually work at a company that is a client of the provider and due to the lack of infrastructure in here we are allowed to crawl it from our private network of the company in order to bring some features to our customers. What exactly do yo mean by copying the requests? I have checked every single detail in the browser but so far not successful.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for assuming things. By copying, I mean that you open your browsers developer tools (right click anywhere on the page and click on 'Inspect'), after that you go to the network tab and refresh the site. Then you can click on the request that you want to send and see exactly which data gets sent. After that, you should go in the Application tab > Cookies > Your site and check which cookies get sent. Add those to your request too and check if it works.

Comment: Yes I have done that several times. I can not really no idea. We have already crawled some other site from this provider with no problem but this time I do not know what is going  on. Do you think there is may be some parameter that blocks the requests from outside browser?

Comment: No there can be no parameter that blocks it from outside a browser, because the only thing that tells a server where the request is coming from is the User-Agent header. Are you sure that you checked the cookies and added them to your request?

Comment: Yes I did check it a lot.Blowing my mind man. did you see the javascript function in my question? there is a parameter called "X-App-N" that gets generated and add to headers. Can you understand it ? I have generated that and sent it with the request but did not change anything. Very weird case.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked that, but it just seems like a sessionId, and you can generate it yourself easily (as you said). Can't really help you with your problem, as I don't have much insight on the request and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot MauriceNino, you actually helped a lot.